# change the color of the borders of my bootstrap table without css

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8

i want to change the color of the borders of my table, i'm using the class .table-bordered the color of borders is grey/silver and i want to change it to black without using css, i used style="border-color:black;" but it doesn't change anything any ideas please ?!!

this is my XML file

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" style="border-color:black;">
                            <tr class="border-black">
                                <th class="text-center">
                                   <h3> Bulletin de paie </h3>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center" align="center">
                                    Adresse 
                                    <br></br>
                                    <span t-field="o.adresse"/> 
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center" align="center">
                                    Date de paie 
                                    <br></br>
                                    <span t-field="o.datedepaie"/> 
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="black">
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    <strong>Matricule</strong>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <span t-field="o.matricule"/>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    <strong>Nom et Prénom</strong>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <span t-field="o.name"/>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    <strong>CNSS</strong>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <span t-field="o.cnss"/>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bordercolor="black">
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    <strong>Date de naissance</strong>
                                <br></br>
                                    <span t-field="o.datenaissance"/>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    <strong>Date d'embauche</strong>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <span t-field="o.dateembauche"/>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    <strong>Fonction</strong>
                                    <br></br>
                                    <span t-field="o.fonction"/>
                                </th>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Libellé</th>
                        <th>Base</th>
                        <th>Taux (%)</th>
                        <th>Gains</th>
                        <th>Retenues</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
                    <tr t-foreach="o.salaire_id" t-as="l">
                        <th><span t-field="l.libelle"/></th>
                        <th><span t-field="l.base"/></th>
                        <th><span t-field="l.taux"/></th>
                        <th><span t-field="l.gains"/></th>
                        <th><span t-field="l.retenues"/></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                                <th colspan="3" class="text-right">
                                <strong>Total</strong>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    <span t-field="o.total"/>
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">    
                                    <span t-field="o.totall"/>
                                </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                                <th colspan="5" class="text-right">
                                    <strong>Net à payer:</strong>
                                    <span t-field="o.net"/>
                                    <br></br>
                                </th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

                    </div>
                 </div>
                  <div class="footer">
```

Comment: You just used inline css, it's still css.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the border color is set on Rows, td's, and th's. It's out of the top of my head though.

You'd need to alter their border color, not the table's

Comment: thank you for your anwer in fact i don't need to lter border color i need to change the color of border to black instead of silver because when i print my report te borders are not clear

Comment: Alter means to change something, you can try what I posted =)

Answer (score 0):

You should post your CSS file. It would be helpful to see the existing styles. Also, line breaks don't require closing tags. I think your `<br></br>` are breaking the HTML.

You only need `<br />`

Comment: @gizzthedj thank you so much for your replay i don't have css file i hope if there is a way to change the color without using css

Comment: I was able to change the border colours to red - just change #F00 to #000 and it should work. Check out https://jsfiddle.net/hco6uhw2/2/. I know you don't want to use CSS, but I'm assuming you want change the style inline? Without seeing the CSS, it is hard to know what styles are being inherited from "table table-bordered" and "border-black". Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you so much it's not workinf for me i don't know why maybe because i'm using XML not HTML ? is that the problem ?